# Data table with bootstrap using angularjs app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jquery data table with bootstrap and facing one little issue which i don't understand.
Here is my code

```
$scope.LoadTypesView = function() {
                           $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : "servierapi.php",
                data    : SessionId,  // pass in data as strings
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            })
                .success(function(data) {

                     if(data.aaData.status=="success") // i get two message error and success and work well
                    {
                               $scope.Type = data.aaData.response;
var oTable = $('#typess').dataTable( {
                                    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                                    "oTableTools": {
                                        "aButtons": [
                                            "copy",
                                            "print",
                                            {
                                                "sExtends":    "collection",
                                                "sButtonText": 'Save <span class="caret" />',
                                                "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "bProcessing": true,
                                    "sAjaxSource": '$scope.Type'
                                } );
                                $('#types').modal('show');    
                    }   
                });
         };
```

Here is my json array which i receive from server and assign to $scope.Type variable

```
   {"aaData":{"status":"success","response":[{"UserTypeId":"1","TypeName":"Admin","CreatedOn":"2014-02-24 00:00:00","AssignedUsers":[{"UserId":"7","UserTypeId":"1","UserRegionId":"1","UserDepartmentId":"1","UserDesignationId":"1","CNIC":"xxxxxxxx","FirstName":"Hafiz","LastName":"Haseeb","Dob":"January 1,1970","PhotoName":"","PhotoPath":"","Email":"xxxxxx","EducationLevel":"","MartialStatus":"","City":"","State":"","Country":"","MobileNumber":"","EmergencyNumber":"","AddressOne":"","AddressTwo":"","CreatedOn":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","Salary":""}]}]}}
```

I also check JSON array on this link http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and json array is valid.
why i am getting this error 
Data Tables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using  "sAjaxSource": '$scope.TypeId' as a string , this is variable you can use this like sample code and some data functions and its parameters

```
                     "sAjaxSource": $scope.TypeId,
                                    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
                                  'fnServerParams' : function (aoData) {
                                    aoData.push({"name":"SessionId",  "value":Session_Id});

                                  }
```

I hope this will help to solve your problem

Comment: Yes @Shoail Yasmin right and i used exactly as you say and my error resolve but one thing i added then you code is run ` $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {'sServerMethod': 'POST' });`  but i face another one problem i get array which i shown up my question and data table not shown

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Display_error = false; this.sign_report.value.status = 0;
  this.signOptions = {pagingType: 'full_numbers', paging: true, ordering: false, dom: 'Bflrtip', pageLength: 10,
  processing: true, serverSide: true, buttons: ['copyHtml5', {extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'To Excel', title: this.in_header},
  {extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: 'To Pdf', title: this.in_header},
  {extend: 'print', text: 'Direct Print', title: this.in_header}],
  ajax:  (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    this.http.post<DataTablesResponse>(this.db.CheckIf_url, dataTablesParameters, {}).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp.data); this.signinoutmodel = resp.data;
      callback({
        draw: resp.draw,
        recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
        data: resp.data
      });
    });
},
fnServerParams: function(dt) {
  dt.signedfrom = fd.signedfrom;
  dt.signedtill = fd.signedtill;
  dt.status = fd.status;
  dt.sort_event = fd.sort_event;
  dt.signed_in_at = fd.signed_in_at;
  dt.signed_out_at = fd.signed_out_at;
  dt.sort_category = fd.sort_category;
},
columns: [{ data: 'tblid' }, { data: 'staff_id' }, { data: 'fullname' }, { data: 'event_name' },
 { data: 'sign_in' }, { data: 'sing_out'}, { data: 'date_signed' } ]
};
```

Comment: You might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.